# Replacing space in url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sorry but I am new in htaccess. I am trying to replace space from my site's url currently my site's urls are like this:

```
http://supremematches.com/About Us.htm
```

and these are working fine I did it using htaccess code bellow:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)\.htm$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I just want to replace speace with - so my site url should be like this:

```
http://supremematches.com/About-Us.htm
```

Please help.

Comment: This is much simpler to change file name... [Stop Using Unsafe Characters in URLs](http://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/)

Answer (score 0):

I just did like this and its working for me.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z].+)$ /page.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Comment: How is this redirecting `/About Us.htm` to `/About-Us.htm`?